# Is there any tool that allows to restart PostgreSQL when there is no more connection slots

Tags: postgresql

Is there any automated tool that allows to restart PostgreSQL or just kill all pending queries on all readers when there is no more connection slots?
The problem is that sometimes all connections to the readers are in use because of unknown reason (slow query may be) and we need quick and dirty solution to monitor the readers and kill all queries when such as event occurs.
I know it's more likely workaround masking the real problem but currently the task I have is to write a script doing this, but I am pretty sure there is already tool I can use instead.
The research I've done led me to the following result: Nagios. 
Unfortunately, I'm still waiting my ticket to be processed by the server support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql Version 9.4

Ref [The Statistics Collector](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/monitoring-stats.html)

```
select pid, query from pg_stat_activity where waiting='t';
```

Ref [Function-Admin: pg_cancel_backend](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-admin.html)

```
select pg_cancel_backend(pid of the postgres process);
```

a Simple bash script. You could even pass in paramters from the command line

```
#!/bin/bash
dbname="Test"
username="postgres"
vartest=`psql -d $dbname -U $username -h localhost -p 5432 -t -c "select  pid from pg_stat_activity where waiting='f';"`
for p_var in ${vartest[@]}
do
# This is an admin function please read more on function-admin in the postgres documentation

# q_result= `psql -d $dbname -U $username -h localhost -p 5432 -t -c "SELECT pg_cancel_backend('$p_var');"`

# sanitiy check just grabs the pid and related query

q_result=`psql -d $dbname -U $username -h localhost -p 5432 -t -c "select pid, query  from pg_stat_activity where  pid='$p_var';"`
done
```