# How to perform iterational update over timeline in PSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I've got a temporary table with timeline. The data are gathered from multiple tables (timeline action a, timeline action b, etc... ):

```
             time
-------------------------------
 2015-02-05 10:45:54.13197+01
 2015-02-05 10:45:56.422353+01
 2015-02-05 10:45:57.518791+01
 2015-02-05 10:46:02.03023+01
 2015-02-05 10:46:02.0821+01
 2015-02-05 10:46:11.584209+01
 2015-02-05 10:46:11.627014+01
 2015-02-05 10:46:11.653886+01
 2015-02-05 10:46:11.688192+01
 2015-02-05 10:48:01.465656+01
 2015-02-05 10:48:02.337642+01
 2015-02-05 12:05:08.088097+01
 2015-02-05 12:05:08.922485+01
 2015-02-05 12:45:49.313329+01
 2015-02-05 12:45:49.363351+01
 2015-02-05 12:45:49.382804+01
 2015-02-05 12:45:49.40134+01
 2015-02-05 12:45:49.416624+01
 2015-02-05 12:45:49.434+01
 2015-03-16 14:21:31.215+01
 2015-03-16 14:22:12.039+01
 2015-03-16 14:22:43.088+01
 2015-03-16 14:58:00.032+01
 2015-06-02 12:53:20.97+02
```

Data needs to be modified, to make each action happen at least 2 minutes after previous action. Ie. minimum difference between two consecutive actions is at least 2 minutes.

In C,C++,Java, or any procedural language I would just iterate over a sorted array and increment value based on previous value (if needed).

How to do it in SQL, or PSQL?

Comment: `psql` is Postgres'  command line tool. The only thing you can use there is "SQL" (the query language). So "in SQL or PSQL" doesn't really make sense (at least not if you **are** talking about Postgres)

Comment: You're right. I'm talking about Postgres. I thought PSQL with same meaning as PostgreSQL :-\

Answer (score 0):

You have several options

1. You can use pg_sleep(seconds) Eg  `SELECT pg_sleep(120);`Ref [postgresql 9.5 pg_sleep](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)
2. PgAgent Ref [PgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent.html)
3. A shell script (This may help you) [stackoverflow question 31382504](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382504/is-there-any-tool-that-allows-to-restart-postgresql-when-there-is-no-more-connec/31392490#31392490)
4. You can set up a cron job Ref  [How to create a Cron job](https://www.howtoforge.com/a-short-introduction-to-cron-jobs)

**Or** the control structures in plsql Ref  [postgresql 9.5 pgSQL control structures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

All the best

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `least()` and `greatest()`. You probably want to do something like the following:

```
UPDATE some_table SET some_time=greatest(some_time,(SELECT previous_time FROM ... ORDER BY previous_time DESC LIMIT 1)+'2 minute'::interval);
```